# Divider in Android recycler view

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I am doing a small Android game where the user needs to assign two players to two teams.
My plan is to use a recycler view which lists all existing players (which are stored in a local database).

The items in the recycler view will be possible to reorder. The first two items in the recycler view will be assigned to team A and the next two items will be assigned to team B. The remaining players will not be considered in a team. The implementation of this logic will be fine, there are also enough examples in the web.

But in order to indicate this logic to the user, I would like to offer him some kind of boxes which indidcate the teams. Like in the following wireframe:

[image]

Does anybody have an advice how this should be done? Should I put a View above the recycler view?
Alternatively, I am also open for alternative approaches to assign exactly two players (uniquely) to two teams.

Comment: I think you should put the A B figures below the recylerview, like a background layer so that they will be independent of your users list.

Comment: check it out https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android

Comment: @amma abdullah not sure how I could use this for my problem. Sure I can add an item displaying some kind of divider line. But then this item is possible to move by drag and drop as well...

Comment: @farrukh tukunov That was the approach I used now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want use RecyclerView, you need to include divider in item view, or make divider as item itself.

Comment: I read quite some pages about dividers, but as I would like to display a frame around two items, dividers are not suitable for that. 

Same issue I have with displaying a divider as a item. With this approach I additionaly have the issue, that I can move it up and down same as the normal items.

Further: What alternative would you suggest beside a recycler view?

Answer (score -1):

You need to place these Divider backgrounds below recyclerview, calculate heights of these items and place it accordingly.

Comment: what kind of divider backgrounds would you use? <View> or images? And why do I need to calculate heights? I also could constrain it to the recycler view, or not?

Comment: I would prefer placing layout behind it which contain both  <view> & <Image> .